# Need plotly colorbar at the bottom

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Here's a dataframe, and the rendered plot using plotly,

I went through the attributes mentioned on plotly R reference guide but couldn't help myself.

```
require(plotly)  
require(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(nn = c(5, 10, 20), Sparsity = c(93.7, 94.3, 94.9
), Method = c("adjcos", "adjcos", "adjcos"), Filtering = c("IBCF", 
"IBCF", "IBCF"), error = c("MAE", "MAE", "MAE"), `5` = c(0.716433082, 
0.746625993, 0.786221009), `10` = c(0.709316631, 0.737244112, 
0.784197414), `20` = c(0.711888414, 0.73875951, 0.783307894), 
    `30` = c(0.716054462, 0.741430884, 0.78574634), `50` = c(0.722296008, 
    0.745516396, 0.788986052), `70` = c(0.727236608, 0.749367689, 
    0.792077439), `100` = c(0.73261171, 0.75337796, 0.795475065
    ), `150` = c(0.738988515, 0.75764295, 0.799090637), `200` = c(0.743606268, 
    0.760689524, 0.801416126)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

plot_ly(x = ~df$Sparsity, y = ~df$nn, z = ~as.matrix(df[,-c(1:5)])) %>%
  add_surface()
```

Plot I obtained

[image]

I need the colorbar/scale (referenced here [colorbar attributes](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#surface-showscale)) at the bottom of the plot, directly rendered from the plot_ly().

> as shown below :

[image]

Comment: Not possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102246/is-it-possible-to-have-a-horizontal-color-bar-in-plotly-js