# Legend to Bottom of Chart and Displayed Horizontally

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

Can anyone tell me how to move the density legend in the map below to the bottom of the chart and have it display horizontally? As you will see, the traditional approach used for doing this with plotly (found in the layout argument) is not working. Alternatively, if anyone can show a way to simply hide the color bar, that would work as well:

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)

density <- sample(1:100, 50, replace = T)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

plot_ly() %>%
  layout(geo = g,
         legend = list(orientation = "h",   
                     xanchor = "center",
                     x = 0.5))  %>% 
  add_trace(type = "choropleth", 
            locationmode = 'USA-states',
            locations = state.abb,
            z = ~density, 
            color = ~density)
```

Edit: Adding `showscale = F` to the trace hides the color bar. Still looking for solutions on displaying it horizontally though!

Comment: It is impossible. See [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102246/is-it-possible-to-have-a-horizontal-color-bar-in-plotly-js)

Comment: Possible if you  fiddle with HTML and CSS.